# Why isn't the Vietnam War called e.g. 抗美战争 ("Resistance War Against America") like in Vietnamese?

Tags: etymology, history

The [Vietnam War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War) is considered by some (most?) Vietnamese people as a fight against [US-led invasion of Vietnam](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2015/04/the-vietnam-war-as-seen-by-the-north-vietnamese/390627/).  Hence...

> The Vietnam War (Vietnamese: Chiến tranh Việt Nam), also known ... **in Vietnam as the Resistance War Against America (Vietnamese: Kháng chiến chống Mỹ) or simply the American War** ...

In contrast, the USA were trying to [inhibit the spread of communism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_theory), i.e., it was an anti-communism war.  So communist China entered to support the North Vietnamese.

In Chinese the Vietnam War is called [越南战争](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B6%8A%E5%8D%97%E6%88%98%E4%BA%89) (literally Vietnam [越南] War [战争], the same as in English).  I find this historically and etymologically curious: there is the phrase [抗日战争](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E6%8A%97%E6%97%A5%E6%88%98%E4%BA%89) ("Resistance War Against the Japanese") which could be easily adapted to 抗美战争, but wasn't.

**Question**: Why isn't the Vietnam War called e.g. 抗美战争 ("Resistance War Against America") like in Vietnamese?

Comment: 抗日戰爭 is a war waged by Japan against China, not against Communism. 抗美戰爭 would only make sense in Vietnamese, not Chinese, as America never invaded China. As you would expect, **Kháng chiến chống Mỹ** (抗戰挵美) means *Resistance War against America*.

Comment: We call the Japan, China war  "抗日战争" because the Japanese was in China waging war against us, so we resisted.

Comment: I wonder what they, the Chinese, (ancient or modern), called it when the Mongols / Manchurians invaded China?

Comment: @WayneCheah I bet you can find the answer in 宋史 and 明史

Comment: @WayneCheah 抗蒙战争, 抗清战争?

Comment: On Wikipedia they call it a Mongol/Manchu *conquest* of China, not an *invasion*

Comment: Most Chinese today probably think of it as a “legitimate part” of Chinese history, due to 二十四史 and all, so they would like to see the conquests as “unifying” the nation

Comment: Thanks everyone for providing a "variety" of answers, much appreciated. BTW, if "...they would like to see the conquests as “unifying” the nation" is correct, then I suppose we can also say a tight slap is a therapeutic face massage? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native Vietnamese names of the Vietnam War are `Chiến tranh Việt Nam` (戰爭越南) and `Kháng chiến chống Mỹ` (抗戰美). If you translate these two Vietnamese names directly into Chinese, they are 越南战争 and 对美抗战 respectively. We Chinese people choose to use 越南战争.

There is another “Resistance War Against America” better-known to China, which is called 抗美援朝战争, literally, “War to Resist America and Aid Chosŏn”, whose English name is the [Korean War](https://www.britannica.com/event/Korean-War). (Note: Chosŏn is the official native Korean name of North Korea.)

Answer (score 4):

Here I come!

The formal name of 抗日战争 is War of Resistance against Japanese Aggression, that involved Chinese themselves, so we(Chinese) have to resist(抗) them(日).

However we are not imediatelly involved in 越南战争, which is an affair of another country, so we would not to use 抗美战争 which literally seems like who resist American are Chinese rather than Vietnamese, because, I conjecture, generally if we see a noun which lacks a subject, we may suggest the missing subject is ourselves.